# How to VLOOKUP in a QUERY

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, vlookup

I Have this sheet with raw data, basically names, dates, amounts of money and if they paid or not (this is the most important). What I am trying to do is to have in another sheet the same table but showing the rows of the people who hasn't paid (filter by a "NO" in "paid" column), and if in the Raw data sheet the value in Paid is changed from NO to YES that row disappears in the "Filtered" sheet.

I am trying to make a VLOOKUP in a query but with no success, any help?

[Example Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GMpThEXwwsWDNcik22dskOBN9-c6ekMjE0RsOF74PUQ/edit?usp=sharing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try:

```
=query(Data!A1:D7,"select * where B ='NO' ")
```

Comment: thanks!! I'm constantly dealing with problems like this, do you know of any tutorial on Google query language?

Comment: sorry to bother you (again), but what if I need to filter also by "type of client" (just saying)?

Comment: haha just added another condition "where XXX and XXX" didn't know it was possible

Comment: @elunicotomas Refer to [this helpful document](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage). Also please note that Google's query language is based on SQL, so that may help with some cases.